# Need help converting data file to specific output

Tags: c++

I have a file named: dataFile (no extension) that contains the following lines:

```
CALCULATOR
Lamp . Post
aBc - deF
```

My program needs to output this data file like this:

```
calculator
lamppost
abcdef
```

so it should basically respect **'\n'**, change all characters to **lower case**, and remove any **non alpha characters**...

Here is my code so far,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
char file;

ifstream cin;
cin.open("dataFile");
cin.get(file);

while (!cin.eof())
    {
    file = tolower(file);                 // Convert all letters to capital letters
         if (('A'<= file && 'Z' >= file)) // Restrict to only letters
            {
             cout << file;                // Output file
            }
    cin.clear();
    cin.get(file);
    }

return 0;
}
```

The problem that I face is that the output of the program looks like this:

> calculatorlamppostabcdef

How should I modify my code so that it outputs each line separately?

Comment: Perhaps output uppercase letters ... and newlines?

Comment: [std::endl](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl)

Comment: It's a 5 line Python script. C++ is not the only language.

Comment: Do you need to use C++, or can you use something else?

Comment: I didn't know you can declare variable named `cin` when including iostream and using namespace std...

Comment: add `if (file == '\n'){cout << endl;}` or `cout << '\n';` before `cin.clear();` or make the if you already have into `if (('A'<= file && 'Z' >= file) || '\n'==file)` whichever you like more

Comment: @zoska well it's local, so it's just incredibly confusing for human readers. But you're right most style-guides disallow or limit variable shadowing.

Comment: I see, I'll try not redefine cin...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use something else, this should do:

```
bash $ (tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' | tr -d -c '[:alpha:]\n') < dataFile
```

Otherwise, this is probably what you want:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char c;
    ifstream file("dataFile");

    while (!file.eof()) {
            c = file.get();

            if (isalpha(c) || c == '\n')
                    cout << tolower(c);
    }

    return 0;
}
```